# Best way to obtain function caller's CPU context

Tags: c++, exception, assembly, x86-64, masm

I am managing standard C++ exceptions and I would like to add CPU context information to them. So, I've created a set of small functions that aid in throwing C++ `(std::exception derived)` exception objects. One of them is a function to grab the caller's context, then it passes it into another function which copies it into an exception object then throws the exception. This is my assembly code for the function (AMD64, MASM, MSVC):

```
EXTERN RtlCaptureContext: PROC

_TEXT SEGMENT

    GrabEHContext PROC

        push rdi ; save modified registers
        push rcx
        push rax

        sub rsp, 1264 ; sizeof shadow space for call & CONTEXT aligned with space for return address to 16 bytes
        mov ecx, 154 ; sizeof(CONTEXT) in QWORDS
        lea rdi, [rsp + 32] ; point to allocated CONTEXT
        xor eax, eax ; store a 0 (memset)
        rep stosq ; do the clear

        lea rcx, [rsp+32] ; set parameter to point to CONTEXT
        call RtlCaptureContext ; do the call

        mov rax, [rsp + 1264] ; get stored RAX
        mov [rsp + 1264 - 120], rax ; update RAX

        mov rax, [rsp + 1264 + 8] ; get stored rcx
        mov [rsp + 1264 - 128], rax ; update rcx

        mov rax, [rsp + 1264 + 8 + 8] ; get stored rdi
        mov [rsp + 1264 - 176], rax ; update rdi

        lea rax, [rsp + 1264 + 24 + 8] ; get previous rsp
        mov [rsp + 1264 - 152], rax ; update rsp

        sub rax, 8 ; point to return address
        mov rax, [rax] ; get the return address
        mov [rsp + 1264 - 248], rax ; update rip to point to return instruction
        
        ; at this point RCX has pointer to caller's CONTEXT
        ; call other function that throws...

    GrabEHContext ENDP


_TEXT ENDS
END
```

I have a few edge cases that I don't know how to handle using my code. So far, it simply grabs the context as best as it can then modifies the values to match the caller's values of `rdi, rcx, rax, rsp, rip`. I am aware that they way I am setting `rip` sets it to the return value, but I cannot find a better way to get the actual address that came right before the caller's `call` instruction.

In addition, I don't know how to best handle machine code that the compiler generates to be

```
sub rsp, 40
jmp GrabEHContext ;no return address / stack to read and fixup
```

Is there a better / more comprehensive way that I can detect these edge cases in the assembly code and act accordingly?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this at least as a source of inspiration (why not have a stack trace like java etc.): https://github.com/JochenKalmbach/StackWalker

Comment: So you want something like the context structure from stackwalk/GetThreadContext https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dbghelp/nf-dbghelp-stackwalk64 ?

Comment: It would help to have more context (no pun intended). What context is `GrabEHContext` supposed to grab? I mean at what point exactly do you want to know the thread context? Your function is almost ok if you want to read the caller ctx, you have to remember that the [volatile registers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170#callercallee-saved-registers) are more then the ones you are saving and you can recompute `rsp` as before the call by adding the (known) size allocated on the stack (I'm not sure where you are reading `rsp` from).

Comment: I don't knwo why the compiler would jump to your function after subtracting 32 bytes from the stack. That would obviously mess up the call. In case of a tail-call, the callee reuse the caller stack setup as is. Also Windows has the context of an exception available for its handler (see `AddVectorExceptionHandler` and `GetExceptionPointers` for legacy SEH). But if you want the context at the throw site, you need to throw a call to a function like `GrabEHContext` (which is what you are trying to do I guess).

Comment: @MargaretBloom `sub 32` was an error on my part, I fixed it to `sub, 40` to account for the 8 bytes taken up by the return address. `GrabEHContext` is supposed to grab the CPU's context prior to calling `GrabEHContext` as best as it can so that I can store that info in a dump to point to the machine state/location before the exception was thrown.

Comment: Basically in WinDbg when the kernel bugchecks and I get debug info saying `exception line/address: [0xfffff80305f60000] > some_bad_code();`, I'm trying to make it so I can write exception data in a dump file and structure the exception context so that I can also get a reading that looks like `exception line/address: [0x7ff754100000] > if (FAILED(some_function)) throw_cpp_error();`

Comment: @ArushAgarampur I still don't see why a compiler would do a `sub rsp, xxx` and then jump to a routine that is supposed to be called. The compiler knows that it must put a return address at the top of the stack before jumping to a function. Anyway, I think you are basically there, just save the volatile registers that could be clobbered by `RtlGetContext` and recompute the original `rsp` from the current value. You can even compute the `rip` before the call, I think with that you get the complete context before the call.

Comment: Got it, I thought the compiler may try to do that because it may detect the function as a `[[noreturn]]`. Quick question though, how is it possible to get the value of `rip` before the call? Because using the return address will only give me `rip` after the call finishes, won't I need to backtrace in memory from the return address and analyze the opcodes to figure out the original value of `rip`?